# How to limit auto orientation to portrait and reverse portrait

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-sensors, android-orientation

The application only automatically goes upside down (reverse portrait) when I have the orientation set to `ScreenOrientation.FullSensor`.

However, it also goes landscape which is what I don't want.

I tried to override the orientation when it changes, but that callback doesn't override the parameters and it continues to execute the orientation change without it returning .

```
    public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Android.Content.Res.Configuration newConfig)
    {
        if (newConfig.Orientation == Android.Content.Res.Orientation.Landscape)
        {
            newConfig.Orientation = Android.Content.Res.Orientation.Portrait;
        }

        base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

How can I automatically orient my xamarin application between portrait and reverse portrait?

Comment: Declare the activity orientation "sensorPortrait". See doc at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen

Answer (score -1):

If you want to overwrite the `OnConfigurationChanged`,you should add below attribute to your activity attribute:

```
ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation|ConfigChanges.ScreenSize|ConfigChanges.KeyboardHidden
```